# How do I select all values in a column corresponding to a specific condition in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that is shown like this:

[image: Data]

I intend to select all numeric values in the 3rd column that correspond to A (e.g. `A1, A2, A3, A4` will give me the selection of `1,3,2,14`).

I understand I have to use something like: `If InStr(firstString, "A") > 0 Then`

But I can't seem to figure out how to add to my selection. I intend to use the selection to transpose the data.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Different possibilities I guess. You could either use `.AutoFilter` with criteria like `"=*A*"` or use `.FindNext` within a range.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a String of the ranges you want to select by going through your loop; Add the cells you want to add in a correct manner to the string, so that it looks something like this:

   `stringRange = "I10,I15,I20,K20,K17"`
2. Select the range:

   `Range(stringRange).Select`